# Is it possible to convert a Simulink block diagram containing integrator block into TwinCAT?

Tags: simulink, twincat, twincat-ads

It is stated that I am trying to convert my control scheme which is implemented in the Simulink into TwinCAT. I have used integrator and derivative blocks in my control scheme.

For testing purposes, I am trying to convert a simple Simulink file containing an integrator block. However, I got a build error. How can I resolve this?

Simulink-block-diagram

[image: Simulink-block-diagram]

Error Picture Simulink during building

[image: Error Picture Simulink during building]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could help us by telling which error you received?

Comment: I have added the error picture.

Comment: HI Muhammad, welcome to StackOverflow. Tip: you can put a `!` in front of the `[]` of image links to show the actual images in the post. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I don't know what is inside your MATLAB Function? Using S-function is not that easy when compiling from Simulink to Beckhoff. See below link.
Can you try an even simpler model where you just pass a variable through? Or where you pass a variable through and multiply by a number.

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/te1400_tc3_target_matlab/4567330059.html&id=

Comment: Yes, I have successfully converted a simple program to TwinCAT in which I added two variable merely. Moreover, I tested this conversion in real-time as well. But when I am trying to use an integrator block then it causes an error.  I have added S-function snapshot. There is a simple for-loop in S-function.

Comment: I would think that the S-function is the problem. Have you tried compiling the integrator without the S-function?

Comment: I am using TwinCAT TE1400 module for stated purpose. One thing I want to mention here is that I also installed TE140x module as well as sample Simulink files. When I select TwinCAT.tlc under Code Generation in Simulink, the model build successfully. However, the model does not show in the TwinCAT TcCOM object under Block Diagram tab. The following error appears: 
Error initializing BlockDiagram PropertyPage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
On the other side, when I used TwinCATGRT.tlc then the model does not build and shows error as Publish failed.